# Is it possible to actually debug 3rd party code using the source decompiled with dotPeek?

Tags: c#, debugging, resharper, decompiling

I use VS2012.

I know how to debug the 3rd party code using the .NET Reflector and always used it.

I was wondering whether this is possible with dotPeek from JetBrains or with R# itself without the dotPeek. I am able to navigate to the decompiled 3rd party code, but not step through it.

Any ideas?

Comment: it is possible with [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)

Comment: I know that - my post states it in the second statement.

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. But this is in JetBrains' near plans.

Comment: @DmitryOsinovskiy - please, arrange it as an answer, so I could credit you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see this question is still driving traffic to my blog, so I'll add an answer: yes, debugging 3rd-party assemblies is now possible with the [JetBrains dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) decompiler (completely free), by using it as a [Symbol server](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/webhelp10/Using_product_as_a_Symbol_Server.html).

In my blog post [How to debug anything with Visual Studio and dotPeek](http://hmemcpy.com/2014/07/how-to-debug-anything-with-visual-studio-and-jetbrains-dotpeek-v1-2/), I detail exactly how to set it up and step into 3rd-party code with the debugger.

Comment: Thank you for our answer Igal, could you consider expanding your answer to include the details in your blog post? This way your answer will still have value if your blog is temporarily or permanently down.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. dotPeek [was released](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/07/16/dotpeek-1-2-is-released/). See [this post](http://hmemcpy.com/2014/07/how-to-debug-anything-with-visual-studio-and-jetbrains-dotpeek-v1-2/) that explains how to do it in details.

Answer (score 2):

Debugging and symbols server are implemented in dotPeek since 1.2 version.
This version is in Early Access now.

More info you can find [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/dotPeek+Symbol+Server+and+PDB+Generation)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, not yet. But this is in JetBrains' near plans.

Comment: Any idea when this is ready? I tried installing R#8 but did not find it.

Comment: Consider updating the answer about decompiler.